# Newton-Euler Inverse Dynamics by Screw

Tags: dynamics, manipulator, screw-theory, inverse-dynamics

I paste this algorithm from textbook `Modern Robotics` P294 in chapter 8:

[image: s]

This is coordinate invariance of Newton-Euler equations. In the textbook, they use the frame is `centers of mass` so the inertial matrix is simple and beautiful, but the result `torque` $\tau$ is applied in the `centers of mass` and NOT in the joint frame. so, when we use this frame, `\tau` maybe need some transformation from centers of mass to the joint frame?

Answer (score 2):

> maybe need some transformation from centers of mass to the joint frame?

Isn't that what $A_i$ is? I don't have the book with me, but from your excerpt:

> Let $A_i$ be the screw axis of joint $i$ defined in $\{i\}$

where it says at the top,

> frames $\{1\}$ to $\{N\}$ [are attached] to the centers of mass of links $\{1\}$ to $\{N\}$

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this. now I just confused the equations $\tau_i = F_i^TA_i$. the textbook says: since joint $i$ has only one degree of freedom, five dimensions of the six-vector $F_i$ are provided `for free` by the structure of the joint(it is clear when $A_i, F_i$ in the same frame), But how to explain  $\tau_i = F_i^TA_i$  from physics, where $A_i$ in the joint frame, and $F_i$ in cm frames.

Comment: I'm sorry to make some mistake in my above comment, $A_i$ is the screw axis of joint $i$ expressed in the `ith` center of mass frame, NOT in the joint frame. so $F_i^TA_i$ still in the center mass frame, and the $\tau$